# CUPS usb printer won't print after restarting the printer

Tags: docker, printing, usb, cups, openmediavault

I have a Samsung_CLP-360_Series usb printer, and a NAS working with OpenMediaVault. My printer is connected to my NAS directly by the USB port. I use CUPS with Docker (I have Portainer on OMV), and everything works fine since the printer doesn't turn off.

But when I restart the printer, it can't print anything anymore. When I send a test page with CUPS to the printer, I have the message "Waiting for printer to become available" on the CUPS Task manager and nothing print.

To make it back working, I have to delete the printer on CUPS and re-add it. I also found out that if I restart the CUPS container, the printer can restart printing as long as it stay on, but when I restart the printer I have the same problem.

How can I make my printer work with CUPS automaticly after restarting the printer without having to manualy restart the cups container ?

Comment: It doesn't look a question related to our SO.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Set standard options in Portainer for [olbat/cupsd](https://hub.docker.com/r/olbat/cupsd): `docker run -d -p 631:631 -v /var/run/dbus:/var/run/dbus --name cupsd olbat/cupsd`
- Add only one another volume: `/dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb`
- Enable privileged mode.